# Spring Boot/Security to Keycloak comm problem

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

I have a variation on this frequent problem that is not addressed by other Qs on this. I have a Spring Boot/Security etc (2.5.6 Boot, 5.5.3 Security, Java 17) serving a REST API and SPA code, using Keycloak 23 for authentication. Both servers are on the same machine (Wintel). I developed this configuring the hostname as localhost running HTTP, and everything worked fine; user was redirected to KC for login, JWT obtained, used for API, SPA code served. I changed to HTTPS and made a self-signed cert, the same cert, for KC and SB. I configged it and installed it in the right places. Again everything worked.

I changed the hostname in the KC and Spring Boot config to the actual name of the machine, and I got the familiar ResourceAccessException when Spring Security tried to configure itself getting the OIDC endpoints on KC. Here is part of the stack trace. Note that there is nothing about invalid cert or other such indication. The URL named in the exception is accessible via Curl and in the browser, returns the expected JSON. Chrome and FF do not complain about untrusted cert.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://myhost:8443/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration": Permission denied: connect; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:670) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.lambda$oidc$0(ClientRegistrations.java:155) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.5.3.jar!/:5.5.3]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.getBuilder(ClientRegistrations.java:208) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.5.3.jar!/:5.5.3]
        ... 97 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579) ~[na:na]
```

Here is the Spring Boot config. The truststore is commented out; the JVM should read cacerts from the JDK. I tried putting cacerts on the classpath but no change. Cacerts contains the certificate that is in the keystore.

```
server:
  port: 443
  ssl:
   enabled: true    
   keyStoreType: PKCS12
   key-store: classpath:myhost.p12
   key-store-password: mypass
   key-alias: myhost
   # JVM should read JDK truststore
   # trust store location
   # trust-store: classpath:cacerts
   # trust store password
   # trust-store-password: changeit
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          #keycloak: 
          myclient:
            client-id: "myclient"
            authorization-grant-type: "authorization_code"          
            scope: "openid"
            provider: "keycloak"     
            authorization-endpoint: https://myhost:8443/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            redirect-uri: 'https://myhost:443'
            issuer-uri: https://myhost:8443/myrealm 
        provider:
          keycloak:
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
            authorization-endpoint: https://myhost:8443/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            authorization-uri: https://myhost:8443/myrealm/
            oidc-provider:  https://myhost:8443/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration 
            issuer-uri: https://myhost:8443/myrealm
            token-uri: https://myhost:8443/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token 
            user-info-uri: https://myhost:8443/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
            logout-uri: https://myhost:8443/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/logout    
            
      resourceserver:
        jwt:   
          issuer-uri: https://myhost:8443/myrealm
          jwk-set-uri: https://myhost:8443/auth/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

Here is the Keycloak config. The keystore is the same file as on the classpath for the Boot app

```
# basic keystore--same file as in Spring Boot app
https-key-store-file=C:/Keycloak/keycloak-23.0.0/conf/certs/myhost.p12
https-key-store-password=mypass

# truststore--JDK truststore, used by JVM
https-trust-store-file=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.1/lib/security/cacerts
https-trust-store-password=changeit
https-trust-store-type=jks

hostname=myhost
hostname-strict-https=true
```

The Keycloak client URIs are as permissible as possible.

Root URL: https://myhost:443
Valid redirect URIs: /*
Web origins: + *

I tried logging to get more info on the error. KC logging even TRACE seems to be mainly about its database (Progres). KC 23 uses Quarkus and I turned on Quarkus logging for HTTP, but only got successful requests, nothing about errors.

This occurs on a VPN if it matters. Is there some problem resolving the hostname? I've used nslookup and nbtstat on myhost, and see the results, and all my adapters and addresses, not sure what to think.

Thanks for any advice.

Later...

The problem appears to be mixing up IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. The unqualified name myhost is presented as v4 wrapped in v6 or something, which fails. One suggestion is to set these variables in the JVM

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false

but it doesn't change the behavior. Another is to use the IP addr, which conflicts with certificate naming, or to use a fully qualified name (and changing the cert). I think the latter choice would work, except that I'm on a VPN, to a remote private domain.

The VPN connection gives me a virtual adapter, and puts an A record in the private domain's DNS, with an IP for the virtual adapter. The FQN of my machine, myhost.privatedomain.com, resolves to that IP, via the DNS of the private domain. That IP is on a different subnet from the rest of the private domain. In any case, from within the private domain, my Keycloak installation can be reached, https://myhost.privatedomain.com:8443.

I am behind my ISP router (Verizon), which has DNS, DHCP and firewall. It gives me a DHCP address, different from the virtual adapter address. NSLOOKUP for myhost.privatedomain.com gives the  virtual adapter address, via the private domain DNS. I cannot reach the virtual adapter address from my machine.

I added an A record for myhost.privatedomain.com to the DNS in my Verizon router, and changed the preferred DNS on my virtual and physical adapters. The local DNS is apparently still bypassed for the private domain DNS, and the virtual adapter addr is returned, for myhost.privatedomain.com. When the VPN is off, the local DNS is used, and returns the local address, the DHCP addr from the Verizon router.

This aim is for the Spring Boot/Security app to contact the Keycloak server; the failure arises during Security configuration. This tangent is a long way around the block.

Comment: Are you sure you added your self-signed certificate to the `cacerts` of the JRE your Spring app is started with?

Comment: I thought of that but when I open the DOS window to run the app JAVA_HOME and the Java version give the correct answers, the Java 17 JDK where the cacerts with the myhost cert is. 

I've been thru many iterations with this and recall that the failure began before I added a cert for localhost, when I changed the hostname to myhost from localhost. There is no firewall in effect, locally anyway. It seems to have something to do with resolving the name and permits on using sockets from somewhere.

Comment: The problem appears to be mixing up IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. See the info under Later at the end of the original (edited) post

Comment: I think the solution to my problem is to move further development into the domain I connect to on VPN, and eliminate these address problems. The app is finished, client and server. Deployment, behind a reverse proxy, is the last step.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a fully qualified name, myhost.mydomain.com for the host name in app configuration. The problem was likely due to confusion of IPv4 and IPv6 addressing in the network stack when using myhost alone, as discussed in the edited question. The solution was complicated by working remotely on a VPN, where my machine was behind a VPN virtual adapter and a Verizon router/fwall/dns/dhcp. The FQN was not addressable from my machine, as explained. I had to "work remotely" on a machine in the home domain. With that the FQN was resolved correctly and the app worked. If there is a simpler answer that would have allowed working on the VPN I'm all ears